# Regex in Lucee refindNoCase

Tags: regex, coldfusion, lucee

I need to convert a piece of code so it works on Lucee.

This is the working code in CF, which does not work in Lucee :

```
  if(structKeyExists(response.responseheader, 'Set-Cookie')) {
        var refind = refindNoCase("JSESSIONID=([\w\d]+);", response.responseheader['Set-Cookie'], 1, true);
        if(structkeyexists(refind, 'match') and isArray(refind.match) and arraylen(refind.match) == 2) {
            variables.sessionId = refind.match[2];
        }
    }
```

response.responseheader['Set-Cookie'] is an array :

```
Array
1   
string  JSESSIONID=CC319C9B3CFA261A72724EAEB36B5C2D; HttpOnly=false; Secure; SameSite=None
```

In CF the output of variables.sessionId = CC319C9B3CFA261A72724EAEB36B5C2D which is exactly what I need.

Lucee throws an error : Can't cast Complex Object Type Array to String, so I changed my code into :

```
        if(structKeyExists(response.responseheader, 'Set-Cookie')) {
            var refind = refindNoCase("JSESSIONID=([\w\d]+);", serialize(response.responseheader['Set-Cookie']), 1, true);
            if(structkeyexists(refind, 'match') and isArray(refind.match) and arraylen(refind.match) == 2) {
                variables.sessionId = refind.match[2];
            }
        }
```

But now variables.sessionId holds 'JSESSIONID=CC319C9B3CFA261A72724EAEB36B5C2D'

How can this be different?
I also tried with hardcoded strings on https://regex101.com/r/cO8lqs/4, giving me only 'CC319C9B3CFA261A72724EAEB36B5C2D')
And when running a code snippet on https://docs.lucee.org/reference/functions/refindnocase.html, giving me 'JSESSIONID=CC319C9B3CFA261A72724EAEB36B5C2D'
Both running with exactly the same string.
How would I go about in Lucee to get what I need, only 'CC319C9B3CFA261A72724EAEB36B5C2D'?
And it needs to run on CF as well, since our production server is still on ACF..

Comment: You have `refind.match[2]`, but you only have one capturing group. Try `refind.match[1]`. Also, does `"(?<=JSESSIONID=)\w+(?=;)"` work?

Comment: What version of Lucee are you on? There was an issue with `reFind()` and `reFindNoCase()` not returning the match array for capture groups correctly, and this was only fixed a few months ago in 5.3.8.80 as per https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-2333?oldIssueView=true

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew I think maybe the serialize makes it quite different. The version we have running on CF (without the serialize) is working and gives us match[2] with the correct value. Trying this (?<=JSESSIONID=)\w+(?=;) but getting an error ' Sequence (?<...) not recognized. I don't know enough about regex functionality to be able to see where this comes from. But I am starting to think about forgetting the use of match and fix this another way.

Comment: @SevRoberts That indeed looks exactly like the issue I am encountering, thanks! Testing on my local via command box, running on 5.3.4.80. I just updated, but it is now giving me  5.3.7.47 so not yet the version in which the match issue is fixed. We also have our test server running on Lucee, but I am not in the position to upgrade and it would take some weeks to get this done I think. For now I will use a workaround, like the one you provided in the answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't explain why it is different in Lucee - which may be a consequence of the bug recently fixed in https://luceeserver.atlassian.net/browse/LDEV-2333?oldIssueView=true - but an answer for your question:

> "How would I go about in Lucee to get what I need, only
> 'CC319C9B3CFA261A72724EAEB36B5C2D'? And it needs to run on CF as well,
> since our production server is still on ACF"

...that gives you the desired result with both Adobe and Lucee, would be to use
`variables.sessionId = listFirst(listLast(refind.match[2],'='),';');`

Standalone example (`var` removed because it's not in a function here) =

```
<cfscript>
response.responseheader['Set-Cookie'] = ["JSESSIONID=CC319C9B3CFA261A72724EAEB36B5C2D; HttpOnly=false; Secure; SameSite=None"];
if(structKeyExists(response.responseheader, 'Set-Cookie')) {
        refind = refindNoCase("JSESSIONID=([\w\d]+);", response.responseheader['Set-Cookie'][1], 1, true);
        if(structkeyexists(refind, 'match') and isArray(refind.match) and arraylen(refind.match) == 2) {
            variables.sessionId = listFirst(listLast(refind.match[2],'='),';');
        }
    }
writeDump(variables.sessionId);
</cfscript>
```

Comment: Thank you. I think I will go with this solution, since I cannot upgrade quickly to see if the fix in version 5.3.4.80. Not sure though if I should flag your response as the answer that solved the problem, because it's more like a workaround. I tended to implement a workaround myself, but kept wondering why the match output was different from CF. Actually your answer above about the lucee fix was the answer that solves the problem :-)

Comment: This covers both of the questions - _"How can this be different?"_ and _"How would I go about in Lucee to get what I need..."_ so I think you should mark this as the answer. But then I would say that :-)

Comment: I agree, the issue is fixed, the cause is clear (by your answers). Thanks again!